# Incorrect template substitution error with g++8.3

Tags: c++, templates

I have the following program -

```
class foo {
    typedef foo type;   
};

template<typename A>
using type_t = typename A::type;

template <typename T>
type_t<T> bar(void){
    return type_t<T>();
}

int main() {
    bar<foo>();
    return 0;
}
```

It is malformed because you cannot access `foo::type` inside bar because it is private (if I make `type` public, the program compiles fine.)

But when I try to compile this with g++8.3, I get the following error -

```
prog.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
prog.cpp:16:11: error: no matching function for call to ‘bar<foo>()’
  bar<foo>();
           ^
prog.cpp:11:11: note: candidate: ‘template<class T> type_t<T> bar()’
 type_t<T> bar(void){
           ^~~
prog.cpp:11:11: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
prog.cpp: In substitution of ‘template<class A> using type_t = typename A::type [with A = foo]’:
prog.cpp:8:32:   recursively required by substitution of ‘template<class A> using type_t = typename A::type [with A = foo]’
prog.cpp:8:32:   required by substitution of ‘template<class A> using type_t = typename A::type [with A = foo]’
prog.cpp:11:11:   required by substitution of ‘template<class T> type_t<T> bar() [with T = foo]’
prog.cpp:16:11:   required from here
prog.cpp:8:32: fatal error: template instantiation depth exceeds maximum of 900 (use -ftemplate-depth= to increase the maximum)
 using type_t = typename A::type;
```

Live here on [Ideone](https://ideone.com/kOCmeB)

What is happening here? Is this a compiler bug or am I not understanding something correctly? Is the typedef being marked as private cause SFINAE to kick in somehow causing it to look for alternate substitutions that are recursive?

Btw, I get the correct error about `type` being private if I don't use the type alias `type_t` and directly define the function `bar` as -

```
template <typename T>
typename T::type bar(void) {
    return typename T::type();
}
```

The error also has nothing to do with the fact that `foo::type` is `foo`. If I change the typedef to `typedef int type`, I still get the same error about recursive substitution.

Comment: Seems to be a GCC-specific thing - clang handles this as expected complaining about private type alias.